# Interact with Google API (2 different PY libraries) google-api-python-client vs google-cloud-storage

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

I’m building a PY application that interacts with Cloud Storage API.

I'm bit confused wit two different approaches to interact with the API:

1. Construct the service object `googleapiclient.discovery.build('storage', 'v1')` for interacting with the Cloud Storage API. Code sample [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/bf62fd639075c64366a48f3a629bdc9b0b0ddfde/compute/auth/application_default.py#L31).

This requires me to install  [Google API Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/)
`$pip install google-api-python-client`

2.Building a `google.cloud.storage.client.Client()` object that interacts with the Cloud Storage API. Documentation [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/client.html).

This, however, requires me to install [Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python)): `$ pip install google-cloud-storage`

I'd like to understand what's the difference between the two approached. Any pros & cons, each method addressing specific use cases? or is it so that one uses the other under the hood ...

Thanks a lot for any clarification!

Cheers!

Comment: Is this not answered on Google's own link? [**Client Libraries Explained**](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained) They compare the same clients you ask about here...

Comment: Thanks a lot! how could I've missed that . But I still dont knwo if both *Cloud Client Libraries* as well as *Google API Client Libraries* are available which is is recommended method. Also I notice, under the hood, Cloud Client libraries use `requests` module vs API Client using `https` module (which perhaps is not ver much recommended anymore?!)

Comment: you can also view the source code for each library on GitHub.